# Vue: Computed property changes in VueTools but the UI not re-rendering

Tags: vue.js

I have the following computed property:

```
 maxQuantity() {
        return (
            (this.getProductSelection &&
                this.getProductSelection.reduce(
                    (x, y) => x + parseInt(y.inventory_quantity),
                    0
                )) ||
            ''
        );
    },
```

In my template, I have:

```
   <div>Maximum Quantity: {{ maxQuantity }}</div>
```

I can adjust products and see the `maxQuantity` computed property value changing in VueTools but the UI isn't reflecting the new value until I refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion. Since Vue performs the getter/setter conversion process during instance initialization, a property must be present in the data object in order for Vue to convert it and make it reactive.

Please refer to the below link

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Comment: Does this apply to Vue 3 and computed properties? I'm having the same issue but on a computed property.